# Problems to display Web Scraping values in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, try-except

I am trying to display an image inside a Tkinter window through Web Scraping displaying a message from a certain point on the website that says in Portuguese "Capella Ganhou" or "Procyon Ganhou".
I tried to look in different forums for a solution but I couldn't find any that fixes the error in my situation. I also tested with print to make sure the string exists and is returning its value and also encapsulated it into a variable.
The source code and the error are below .

```
from tkinter import *
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from IPython.display import Image, display
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import io

def capella_tg():
    resultado_tg = StringVar()
    resultado_tg.set(soup.find_all("font")[5].string)
    label_resultado_tg = Label(root, textvariable=resultado_tg).pack()

def procyon_tg():
    resultado_tg = StringVar()
    resultado_tg.set(soup.find_all("font")[4].string[3:])
    label_resultado_tg = Label(root, textvariable=resultado_tg).pack()

def img_capella():
    raw_data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.imgur.com/AHLqtt0.jpg").read()
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    label1 = Label(root, image=image).pack()

def img_procyon():
    raw_data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.imgur.com/TQyCnfD.jpg").read()
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    label1 = Label(root, image=image).pack()

root = Tk()

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.cabaleasy.com") as url: page = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
#print(soup.find_all("font")[5].string)

try:
    capella_tg()
except:
    procyon_tg()

if capella_tg():
    img_capella()
elif procyon_tg():
    img_procyon()

root.mainloop()
```

-------ERROR---------

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LucasDEV/PycharmProjects/LucasDEV/WEB_SCRAPPING/TESTES.py", line 49, in <module>
    elif procyon_tg():
  File "C:/Users/LucasDEV/PycharmProjects/LucasDEV/WEB_SCRAPPING/TESTES.py", line 17, in procyon_tg
    resultado_tg.set(soup.find_all("font")[4].string[3:])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Hello, @Lucas Ribeiro, You have an issue in this function 'def procyon_tg'  where you access the data from soup.find_all("font")[4].string[3:] but approach is no justify with the data. Try to trace this line to remove the extra opt and after add the suitable string operation.

Comment: @Dipen Shah

That is why I used the try/except structure for. But it's not working and I'm getting the same error. I also tried this way:

`def capella_tg():
    resultado_tg = StringVar()
    try:
        resultado_tg.set(soup.find_all("font")[5].string)
        label_resultado_tg = Label(root, textvariable=resultado_tg).pack()
    except:
        pass`

Answer (score 0):

@Dipen Shah That is why I used the try/except structure for. But it's not working and I'm getting the same error. I also tried this way:

```
def capella_tg():
    resultado_tg = StringVar()
    try:
        resultado_tg.set(soup.find_all("font")[5].string)
        label_resultado_tg = Label(root, textvariable=resultado_tg).pack()
    except:
        pass
```

i tested just using text and it works:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.cabaleasy.com") as url: page = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

try:
    print(soup.find_all("font")[5].string) 
    #At this moment, it will not be showing, cuz the status changes every hour
except:
    print(soup.find_all("font")[4].string[3:])
```